# Print static image in qweb report

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I can't display a static image in qweb report, this is my code:

```
                    <div class="header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-8">
                                <img src="/my_module/static/src/img/logo.png" width="200" height="100"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Check if the system paramater `web.base.url` is correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

Go in the Odoo font-end, click on edit -> Add image.

When you add this image, click to open this image in a new tab. You will have a link like :

yourodoowebsite.com/name_of_image.png

This link, you will copy past into your code :

```
                   <div class="header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <img src="yourodoowebsite.com/name_of_image.png" width="200" height="100"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```